# Which Pest Attacked My Lettuce Leaves?

Tags: pests, pest-damage, lettuce

I planted romaine lettuce and I think it was attacked by some pests, but I can't identify them because I don't see any insects. I decided to replace with the new plants but it still get attacked. Do you know which pest attack my lettuce like in this picture?

If you need more description about my location or anything else, please comment this post :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This rather looks like hydroponic lettuce that has been attacked by birds. You don't say what area of the world, so no point in speculating about specific bird species, but maybe something which can hover while it uses a sharp beak to grab juicy leaf sections. Some of the cuts look scissor clean and clearly they are after the young tips. If your local weather has been dry and the air has been low in humidity then your lettuce might be the most convenient source of moisture. Look for claw marks on your equipment which might indicate birds landing.

Here is [a short article](http://ashfordallotmentsorguk.weebly.com/bird-damage.html) on bird damage in the UK.

Comment: I think you're right. The weather in my location has been dry for weeks. When you mention about birds, actually there are sparrows flying around my hydroponic lettuce but never see them landing.